# My Firebase Security Rule won't allow me to write on another user's node, why?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have tried a few things but none worked...

I'm implementing a "**block user**" functionality in my app, when `user A` blocks `user B`, I am writing to a child node of both users's `block-user` and `blocked-by-user` child nodes respectively.

```
Error: setValue: or removeValue: at /users/$uid/blocked-by-users/-LPi46QePJLDWIrrU45y failed: permission_denied
```

I wish to update the following rule to allow to write on another user's `uid` child nodes called `blocked-users` and `blocked-by-users`

```
"users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      },
        ".read": "auth != null"
    },
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    "users": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".read": "auth != null"
    },
```

This will work, if you don't have any security issue:)

Comment: Yeah I have temporarily changed the rules to this, but this is simply allowing anyone that has been authenticated to write on anyone’s user node. Not sure that is the safest approach :/